# NameError: name 'update' is not defined PONYORM

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, ponyorm

I run the following code to update a record with where condition by ponyorm in Python 3.8.5

```
from pony.orm import *

customer = update(c.set(CustomerCode = '123') for c in Customers if c.CustomerCode == '456')
```

But, I got NameError as follows.

```
NameError: name 'update' is not defined
```

Any idea?

Thaks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PonyORM` does not currently support bulk update in the way that you are trying to use it, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.ponyorm.org/working_with_entity_instances.html#updating-an-object).

Relevant snippet:

[image: unsupported]

So to answer your question: `PonyORM` does **not** have an `update` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, how can I update a record by a where condition by ponyorm?